# Why do I get undefined value when I reuse it while pushing the key-value pairs into the $scope object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to add the comment to the `$scope.comments` array. All key-value pairs are being pushed into `$scope.comments` except for the initial key. Which has to shorten the `capitaliseUsername(comment.owner)`.

```js
$scope.comments.push({
  id: comment.id,
  text: comment.text,
  timestamp: comment.timestamp,
  owner: comment.owner,
  card: comment.card,
  initial: capitaliseUsername(comment.owner) //why is comment.owner value undefined here
}
```

Yet comment array returned from the server contains `comment.owner` value because the owner key works perfectly.

Check the screenshot of the JSON data returned for the comments.

Comment: You probably forgot to **return** the value: `function capitaliseUsername(user){ return user[0].toUpperCase() + user.substring(1); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function capitaliseUsername(comment.owner) have to need return something that assign in "initial" in comments array;

Here comment.owner is ok but as the capitaliseUsername(comment.owner) has no return and for this "initial" is assign with undefined.

Comment: Thank you for help. I finally realised that i was not returning the comment.owner data to the capitaliseUsername  function. I think it was due to switching to different git branches. because for loading the blog comments it was working perfectly.. except adding the comments.